# how can we create a block size in jmeter with csv config? Each thread should pickup specific set of values

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

how can we create a block size in JMeter with CSV config?

I have 5 multiple users and one Bulkuser.csv file with 4 columns,

The file has around 2000 values.
I wish to create a block of 400 values for my 5threads[users].
1st USER WILL USE 1st – 400 VALUES (Values in ROW 1-400)

2nd USER WILL USE NEXT 5 VALUES (Values in ROW 401-800)
and so on..

How can we implement this? is there a beanshell pre-processor script for each data read and decide to read the specific file as per thread number?

Answer (score 0):

As of [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) this functionality is not supported, the only stable option I can think of is splitting your `Bulkuser.csv` into 5 separate files like `user1.csv`, `user2.csv`, etc. and use [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) and [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) functions combination for accessing the data like:

- `${__CSVRead(user${__threadNum}.csv,0)}` - reads the value from column 1 from user1.csv file for 1st thread (for 2nd thread it will be user2.csv file, etc)
- `${__CSVRead(user${__threadNum}.csv,1)}` - reads the value from column 2
- .....
- `${__CSVRead(user${__threadNum}.csv,next)}` - proceeds to the next row

More information: [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime)